# Linux, using libconfig library

Tags: linux, libconfig

Simple task to open wifi.conf with libconfig library ends with "Parse error at /tmp/wifi.conf:6 - syntax error"

The "problem" config line is just:
WIFI_MODE=sta

Sources:

```
#include <libconfig.h++>
```

...
cfg.readFile("/tmp/wifi.conf");
...

What can be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue: not quoted string data.